# MySQL query return unexpected values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Need to generate courses list and count

1. all
2. unanswered
3. answered but unchecked

Questions.

My database structure is looking like that

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B9ExyO6ktYcOenZ1WlBwdlY2R3c

Explanation for some of tables:

1. `answer_chk_results` - checked answers table. So if some answer doesn't exist on this table, it means it's unchecked
2. `lesson_questions` - lesson <-> question associations (by id) table
3. `courses-lessons` - courses <-> lessons associations (by id) table

Executing

```
    SELECT
    c.ID,
    c. NAME,
    COUNT(lq.id) AS Questions,
    COUNT(
        CASE
        WHEN a.id IS NULL THEN
            lq.id
        END
    ) AS UnAnswered,
    COUNT(
        CASE
        WHEN cr.id IS NULL THEN
            lq.id
        END
    ) AS UnChecked
FROM
    courses c
LEFT JOIN `courses-lessons` cl ON cl.cid = c.id
LEFT JOIN `lesson_questions` lq ON lq.lid = cl.lid
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.qid = lq.qid
LEFT JOIN answer_chk_results cr ON cr.aid = a.id
GROUP BY
    c.ID
```

Tested it first on [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d23b4/44) with sample data. (Real data is huge, so I can't place it on sqlfiddle) It returned some values. Thought works well. But while I test it with real data, see that returns wrong values. Forex, when I manually count, result for `all questions count` must be 25, but it returns 27. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

*Note* MySQL server running on my local machine, so I can give you [teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com) id and password if you want to connect to my desktop remotely and test query with real data.

Comment: The SQLfiddle to which you've linked and the query that you've given in your question are not the same.  Which gives the incorrect results on your live data?

Comment: @eggyal updated link, they are same.

Comment: Well, I guess there might be a 1-to-n relation. As we don't see cardinalities anywhere this is a hard guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that different joins are resulting in a multiplication of rows.  The best way to fix this is by using subqueries along each dimension.  The following is a more practical way.  Replace the COUNTs in the select with COUNT DISTINCT:

```
SELECT c.ID, c. NAME,
       COUNT(distinct lq.id) AS Questions,
       COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN a.id IS NULL THEN lq.id END) AS UnAnswered,
       COUNT(distinct CASE WHEN cr.id IS NULL THEN lq.id END) AS UnChecked
```

Compared to COUNT, COUNT DISTINCT is a resource hog (it has to remove duplicates).  However, it will probably work fine for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT
    c.ID,
    c.NAME,
    COUNT(lq.id) AS Questions,
    COUNT(IFNULL(a.id),lq.id)AS UnAnswered,
    COUNT(IFNULL(cr.id),lq.id)AS UnChecked,
FROM    courses c
LEFT JOIN `courses-lessons` cl ON cl.cid = c.id
LEFT JOIN `lesson_questions` AS lq ON lq.lid = cl.lid
LEFT JOIN answers a ON a.qid = lq.qid
LEFT JOIN answer_chk_results cr ON cr.aid = a.id
GROUP BY c.ID
```